# Using the Pattern Attribute in HTML5

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have a form in HTML5 and I want to add validation elements to the name, address and phone fields. So far I have the following code:

```
name='name' pattern='(-.''[A-Za-z])'
name='phone' pattern='[0-9+()x-' ']'
name='address' pattern='[0-9A-Za-z][.,#/\:;''&*]'
```

For the name, I need it to be able to accept the `-'.` symbols.
For the phone, I need it to be able to accept `+()0-9 x` and space.
For address, I need it to be able to accept all of the characters I've put there.

I'm not sure I've done it right though, as when testing I don't get error messages.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder : `Never trust the user`. Never forget back-end values verification.

Comment: It appears you're not very familiar with regex. I highly recommend learning using a tutorial, but there's also many pre-made regexes already available online, such as ones on [this site](http://html5pattern.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the pattern in `"` as you are also using `'` within your pattern itself.

Sample for the `name` field, including the correct pattern string:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" required pattern="[-.'A-Za-z]+" /><input type="submit">
</form>
```

(assuming you want to allow `-'.` *plus* the characters, your requirements are not 100% clear to me)

Comment: Thanks Marvin.  Great help...that fixed the issues :)